# SASS Button with transparent Background and 1px white border

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have a hard time figuring out how to define a button with a transparent background, a white text and a 1px white outline.

I currently work with this:

```
.mybutton {
  @include button-base();
  @include button-size($button-tny, false);
  @include button-style(false, true, false, null, #FF0000);
}
```

I've read [the source](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_buttons.scss) but it looks like there is nothing to begin with. There is only a color-definition for the border (I found then $button-border-width but am yet puzzled to use it).

So to learn something from this let me rephrase the question:
How can I set a button:

- no Background
- 2px solid border
- white text
- border should be .3 alpha/opacity (is this possible or only the whole button?)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know that `button-style` sets the variables on which `$button-base` is based on.
See this - https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_buttons.scss#L143

so I have not tried this, but if you reverse the order, it might work

```
.mybutton {
  @include button-size($button-tny, false);
  @include button-style(false, true, false, null, #FF0000);
  @include button-base();
}
```